# Unable to install selenium webdriver

Tags: java, node.js, selenium

I am getting below message on installing of selenium webdriver

```
vikas@vikas-pc:~$ npm install selenium-webdriver
| |---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
WARN engine selenium-webdriver@3.6.0: wanted: {"node":">= 6.9.0"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine selenium-webdriver@3.6.0: wanted: {"node":">= 6.9.0"} (current: {"novikas@1.0.0 /home/vikas
`-- selenium-standalone@6.11.0
```

Addition to this version check

```
vikas@vikas-pc:~$ node -v
v4.2.6
vikas@vikas-pc:~$ npm -v
3.5.2
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something here, but the error message seems to say that it requires a node version higher or equal to 6.9.0 and the one you have installed is 4.2.6. Does updating help?

Comment: Yes I understand it but how to upgrade it then after?

Comment: I'm sure there are instructions somewhere on how to update node.js in your specific environment / OS

Comment: I am trying many ways but no luck

Comment: Go to download the installer from https://nodejs.org/

Comment: What should I do next after unzipping it?